# Customize the way Static File is displayed nextjs?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is it possible to customize how static files(mainly images) are displayed?

For example, when we visit a static file of a site: https://c.tenor.com/-mHyVN9SAzoAAAAC/henry-sad-henry.gif

It basically shows a simple `img` element. Can I dynamically render extra elements there keeping the url as it is(ends with file name and extension)

Basically, I want to use my site's image in a subreddit which supports direct links only(ends with file name and extension), but also want to show my site's name and some other stuffs with the image.

I am using Next.JS framework

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes and no.

When you load a static image into the main browser viewport then *the browser* will generate a simple HTML document to display it in.

If you want to display a custom HTML document then you need to serve up your own HTML document.

That basically boils down to providing a [route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction). You can use `:slug` syntax to substitute in the filename of the image and then load it into the `src` of your image (after sanitising it to prevent, for example, people dropping in a URL that resolves to a third-party hosted offensive image that gets surrounded by your branding).

However, if you are doing that then — while the URL will end with the filename and extension — it **won't** be a *direct link* so it will violate the rules.